# Fluent NHibernate subclass reference

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, subclass, nhibernate-mapping

So I have following entities:

```
TimelineRecord:
    ID: PK
    From: DateTime
    To: DateTime

ServiceRecord extends TimelineRecord:
    ID: PK
    TimelineRecord_ID: FK
    SomeSpecificProperties...

Demand:
    ID: PK
    From: DateTime
    To: DateTime
    ...

ServiceDemandConnection:
    ID: PK
    Service: ServiceRecord
    Demand: Demand
```

TimelineRecord, Demand and ServiceDemandConnection are mapped using ClassMap
with Id(x => x.Id). ServiceRecord is mapped using SubclassMap (table-per-class).
References in ServiceDemandConnection are mapped using References(x => x.Service).Cascade.None() and the same for .Demand.

The problem is with inserting ServiceDemandConnection with properly set ServiceRecord and Demand.
I get an error: Detail=Key (servicerecord_id)=(8) is not present in table "ServiceRecord". What error states is true. 8 is the ID of TimelineRecord, not ServiceRecord. However, ID of ServiceRecord (TimelineRecord_ID, which is actually not mapped/not accessible in the code) should be used instead. The current mapping hides ServiceRecord.ID.

How should I tell NHibernate to use ID of the subclass table (ServiceRecord), and not of the base class table (TimelineRecord)? NHibernate actually creates a proper constraint in the database, but during runtime it violates it somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either

- map `ServiceRecord` as separate class not using `SubclassMap` to use it's `ID`
- or use `ID` from base class and do not map it inside `SubclassMap`

The second approach works because `SubclassMap` creates a `FK` relationship between child and parent object so that data is consistent and you have something like

```
TimeLineRecord
  ID : PK

ServiceRecord extends TimelineRecord:
  TimelineRecord_ID: FK -----> TimeLineRecord.ID
```

It is still valid to point references to child classess.

Comment: I'd like to preserve the inheritance. The second option is possible, but then I will not have the proper constraint in DB. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes you will. The ID with second option exists only in base class and child class only maintains FK to parent. It is redundant to keep id's on both levels and this can lead to issues

Comment: By _proper constraint_ in this context I meant a constraint on ServiceDemandConnection.Service FK. With your second approach I would need to change the type of ServiceDemandConnection.Service from ServiceRecord to TimelineRecord and check its validity in business logic. Am I missing something?

Comment: I misunderstood your hint about keeping ID's on both levels. It is redundant. The second solution is working for me.